# Apply to everyone with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I record meals in this way, as I show in the image:
[image]

I created the **Apply to All** button, which is to fill the remaining days of the month with the same data after completing the 1st of the month. For example:

I pre-pack the day 1:

[image]

By clicking the **Apply to All** button fill the remaining days in the same way:

**Code:**

```
<input type='button' id='elemento' value='Aplicar a Todos' />

<td bgcolor='$color' data-semana=''><font size='2px'/> 

  <input id='firstCB{$year}{$month}{$day}' type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][dia]' value='$year-$month-$day'>$year-$month-$day <br /> 
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço'>Peq. Almoço</div> <div><input ref='firstCB{$year}{$month}{$day}' min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' />

  <br />

  </div> 
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox1' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][opcaoB]'  value='Almoço'>Almoço</div> <div><input ref='firstCB{$year}{$month}{$day}' min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd1]' value='$marcado_almoco_qtd'/> 

    <br /> 

  </div>
</td>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#elemento').on('click', function(){
  var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']")];
   if(inputs == 'checked'){ // condição
      $('.checkbox').prop('checked', true);
      $('.checkbox1').prop('checked', true);
   }
});
```

I wanted you to select all the checkboxes on every day as on day 1 and also fill in the inputs with the same value as day 1. 
As I have the condition does not select any checkbox when clicking the **Apply to all** button.

Comment: `inputs` is an array of all elements with `type=checkbox`. You check if it is equal to a string. `[] != ""`.

Comment: @Bruno, you can check my jQuery implementation. it seems your click handler on the button is messing up the state of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem of applying to everyone in the following way:

```
$('#elemento').click(function() {
  var checkedValues = Array(8).fill(false);
  var textValues = Array(7).fill('');
  var checkedStep = 0;
  var textStep = 0;
  $('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value){
    if(index < 8){
      checkedValues[index] = $(this).prop("checked");
    }else{
      if(checkedStep == 8){
        checkedStep = 0;
      }
      $(this).prop('checked', checkedValues[checkedStep++]);
    }
  });
  $('tr').find('input[type="number"]').each(function(index, value){
    if(index < 7){
      textValues[index] = $(this).val();
    }else{
      if(textStep == 7){
        textStep = 0;
      }
      $(this).val(textValues[textStep++]);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you are using JQuery, but heres an option in vanilla JS. Talvez te servia melhor. Portugal Ale!

```js
const dayChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.day input[type="checkbox"]');
const dayInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.day input[type="number"]');
const btn = document.querySelector('#click');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   dayChecks.forEach( input => { // Handles checkboxes
      if(input.checked){
         const elClass = input.parentElement.getAttribute('class');
         const allEls = document.querySelectorAll(`.${elClass}`);
         allEls.forEach( (el) => {
            el.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
         });
      }
   });

   dayInputs.forEach( input => { // Handles Inputs
      if(input.value != ''){
         const value = input.value;
         const elClass = input.parentElement.getAttribute('class');
         const allEls = document.querySelectorAll(`.${elClass}`);
         allEls.forEach( (el) => {
            el.querySelector('input[type="number"]').value = value;
         });
      }
   });

});
```

```css
.week {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
      }
      .day{
         padding: 20px;
      }
```

```html
<button id='click'>Apply to All</button>

   <div class="week">
      <div class="day">
         <h2>Primeiro Dia</h2>
         <div class="peqAlmoco">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
            <input type="number" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="almoco">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
            <input type="number" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="jantar">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
            <input type="number" value="">
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="day">
         <h2>Segundo Dia</h2>
         <div class="peqAlmoco">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
            <input type="number" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="almoco">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
            <input type="number" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="jantar">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
            <input type="number" value="">
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="day">
         <h2>Terçeiro Dia</h2>
         <div class="peqAlmoco">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
            <input type="number" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="almoco">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
            <input type="number" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="jantar">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
            <input type="number" value="">
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an elegant JQuery implementation try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // used the first checkbox (input with the date class) to select each data column for entering data
    // this is the column you want replicated on other columns
    $('.date').change(function() {

        // inactivate every other column that is not this column
        $('.date').not($(this)).prop('checked', false).parents('td').removeClass('active');

        // show that this is the currently selected column
        $(this).parents('td').toggleClass('active');
    });

    // click handler for 'apply to all' button
    $('#elemento').click(function() {

        var checkboxstate = {}; // object to store all the checkbox state in the current column
        var numberstate = {}; // object to store content of all text input in the current column

        // for each input element in the active column
        $.each($('.active').find('input'), function(key, element){

            if($(this).prop('type') == 'checkbox') {

                // collect all checkbox state
                checkboxstate[element.name] = $(this).prop('checked');

            } else {

                // collect all input text content
                numberstate[element.name] = $(this).val();
            }
        });

        // for each checkbox or number
        $.each($('.checkbox, .number'), function(key, element) {
            // store these variables beforehand so you don't need to test for them in the inner each statement

            // for checkboxes
            var target = checkboxstate;
            var type = 'checkbox';
            var property = 'checked';

            // for number elements
            if($(this).is('.number')) {
                target = numberstate;
                type = 'number';
                property = 'value';
            }
            
            // assign object properties to dom elements with same type and name properties as that of the object property
            $.each(target, function(key_1, element_1) {
                if($(element).prop('type') == type && $(element).prop('name') == key_1) {
                    $(element).prop(property, element_1);
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <title>My test doc</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .active {
                background-color: #00ff00;
            }
            input {
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
            .checkbox-div {
                float: left;
            }
            .number-div {
                float: right;
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>welcome</h3>
        <form method="GET" action="#">
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="date" type='checkbox' name='date' value='date'>Date 
                    <br/> 
                    <div class="checkbox-div">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='Peq_Almoço' value='Peq_Almoço'>Peq. Almoço
                    </div>
                    <div class="number-div">
                        <input min='0' type='number' class='number' name='Peq_Almoço' value='' />
                    </div> 
                    <br/>
                    <div class="checkbox-div">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='Almoço'  value='Almoço'>Almoço
                    </div>
                    <div class="number-div">
                        <input min='0' type='number' class='number' name='Almoço' value=''/>  
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="checkbox-div">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='Lanche'  value='Lanche'>Lanche
                    </div>
                    <div class="number-div">
                        <input min='0' type='number' class='number' name='Lanche' value=''/>  
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="date" type='checkbox' name='date' value='date'>Date 
                    <br/> 
                    <div class="checkbox-div">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='Peq_Almoço' value='Peq_Almoço'>Peq. Almoço
                    </div>
                    <div class="number-div">
                        <input min='0' type='number' class='number' name='Peq_Almoço' value='' />
                    </div> 
                    <br/>
                    <div class="checkbox-div">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='Almoço'  value='Almoço'>Almoço
                    </div>
                    <div class="number-div">
                        <input min='0' type='number' class='number' name='Almoço' value=''/>  
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="checkbox-div">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='Lanche'  value='Lanche'>Lanche
                    </div>
                    <div class="number-div">
                        <input min='0' type='number' class='number' name='Lanche' value=''/>  
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="date" type='checkbox' name='date' value='date'>Date 
                    <br/> 
                    <div class="checkbox-div">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='Peq_Almoço' value='Peq_Almoço'>Peq. Almoço
                    </div>
                    <div class="number-div">
                        <input min='0' type='number' class='number' name='Peq_Almoço' value='' />
                    </div> 
                    <br/>
                    <div class="checkbox-div">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='Almoço'  value='Almoço'>Almoço
                    </div>
                    <div class="number-div">
                        <input min='0' type='number' class='number' name='Almoço' value=''/>  
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="checkbox-div">
                        <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='Lanche'  value='Lanche'>Lanche
                    </div>
                    <div class="number-div">
                        <input min='0' type='number' class='number' name='Lanche' value=''/>  
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type='button' id='elemento' value='Aplicar a Todos' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also see the Fiddle sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/udochify/w9a65Lvh/4/)

Here, each column is represented by a `td` element. I used the first checkbox with the `date` class to select the column we want other columns to replicate.

Also, the checkbox and number inputs are loosed coupled - that is, a checkbox can be unchecked with the corresponding number input filled and this will still be replicated on other columns.

Three columns were used for brevity. You can create as many columns as you want and the jQuery script will still run seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `inputs` is a collection of inputs, therefore you have to check the state of each input in a `forEach` or a for `loop`.

Same for other inputs that you want to modify the state.

Code:

```
$('#elemento').on('click', function(){
  var inputs = $('td > input');

  inputs.each(function(index, element){
    if(element.checked) {
       var children = $(element).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]');

      children.each(function(i, child){
        $(child).prop('checked', true);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You are not selecting the remaining days of the month

Comment: Now it does select the remaining days (.checkbox and .checkbox1)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply classes to each checkbox and select all checkbox on click of **Apply to All** button

```
<input type="checkbox" class="Almoco" />

$('#elemento').on('click', function(){
   if(check for your condition if you need to apply check for all checkboxes)
   {
      $('.Almoco').prop('checked', true);
   } 
   //Similiarily check for other checkboxes
});
```

Comment: my difficulty is how to check if the checkbox is selected. I want to check the selected checkboxes on day 1, and if they are selected, I select on the remaining days of the month

Comment: you can use a different class to identify the first day of the month or you can use the first index of  $('.Almoco') like  $('.Almoco')[0] to access the checked value of the checkbox.

Comment: can place the example in the code that posted above in response?